# Как создать гиперссылку по условию?

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Доброго времени суток!

Смысл в следующем: На одном из листов имеем оглавление в виде таблички. Там есть 2 скрытых столбца, **D** - Имя ссылки, **E** - имя листа.
В столбце **C** формируем ссылку:

```
=ЕСЛИ(E6="-";D6;ГИПЕРССЫЛКА("#'"&E6&"'!L24";D6))
```

Т.е. если вместо имени листа '-', то берём просто текст из **D**, иначе создаём ссылку по имени листа из **E**.
Тут как бы первая проблема... Почему если условие ложно, то ссылка всё равно создаётся? Просто она битая и при клике пишет невозможно открыть указанный файл. Как сделать по условию правильно?

И на каждом листе я делаю ссылку назад(именно на строку вызова), такого вида:

```
=ГИПЕРССЫЛКА("#'Table of contents'!D"&ПОИСКПОЗ(ПСТР(ЯЧЕЙКА("filename");ПОИСК("]";ЯЧЕЙКА("filename"))+1;31);sheetsTable;0)+2;"Back")
```

Поиск по таблице для того, чтобы если оглавление будет отсортировано или отфильтровано, ничего не ломалось..
Оно работает, почти правильно, только я не понимаю почему прыгает на столбец **C** вместо заданного **D**?

Comment: По второму вопросу: с помощью `ПОИСКПОЗ` Вы ищете номер строки в имени листа: `ПОИСКПОЗ(имя_листа;sheetsTable;0)+2` Это правильно?

Comment: Да, именно так и пытаюсь туда спозиционироваться. +2 это шапка

Comment: Покажите пример, иначе непонятно, как сортировка на листе зависит от имени листа

Comment: sheetsTable это сама табличка с оглавлением

Comment: Вы же не на листе ищете, а в его имени!

Comment: Пример смогу только к вечеру показать, сейчас с телефона... Позиция там находится правильно, интересно почему я задаю её !D, а позиционируется в столбец C?

Comment: Нет, вы не так поняли. Ссылка назад у нас на каждом из листов, имя которого мы берём, а sheetsTable это именованный диапазон на листе оглавления, в одном из столбцов которого находится список имён листов. Вторым параметром мы как раз диапазон же задаём https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%97-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%98%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%97-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a

Comment: `ПСТР` возвращает имя активного листа. **Не ссылку - текст**. Вы в тексте (не на листе) пытаетесь найти диапазон листа

Comment: Разве не наоборот? Я в диапазоне на другом листе ищу название текущего листа... Ладно я ближе к вечеру мини примерчик сделаю, так нагляднее будет.

Comment: Короче это какой-то баг местного характера был. Скопировал формулу в соседнюю ячейку, стало работать правильно. потом стёр и вставил где было и тоже заработало.

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4tGF/58sadEe9e

Comment: Прошу прощения, перемкнуло :) я действительно все перепутал...

Answer (score 1):

`Excel` видит гиперссылку и сначала вставляет ее, потом формирует по условию.

Используйте макрос. Код в модуле листа

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D:E"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        With Target
            Cells(.Row, 3).Hyperlinks.Delete
            Cells(.Row, 3).Value = Cells(.Row, 4).Value

            If Cells(.Row, 5).Value <> "-" Then
                Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(.Row, 3), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Cells(.Row, 5).Value & "'!L24"
            End If
        End With

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Макрос реагирует на изменения в столбцах *D:E* и вставляет в столбец *С* или просто значение, или гиперссылку.

Comment: Да в макросе то это всегда не проблема, я надеялся обойтись без них... Жаль, если это невозможно.

Comment: А по второму вопросу? Что-то я там с синтаксисом напортачил? Или почему он себя так странно ведёт?

Comment: хм... у меня WPS Office бесплатный и там вообще похоже нет поддержки макросов( Придётся функционал условного оператора переложить на себя...